# Why is It still can't import SVG when I followed the Installation and configuration with the SVG library in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

I want to import an SVG file into React Native project. I followed the installation and configuration by react-native-svg-transformer.But it still have error

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./svg/ABC.svg from /src/asset/images/index.ts: 

None of these files exist:
  * src/asset/images/svg/angle.svg(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
  * src/asset/images/svg/angle.svg/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
```

Here is my configuration.

`metro.config.js`

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: ["db", "mp3", "ttf", "obj", "png", "jpg", "glb", "gltf", "fbx"].filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
  };

  return config;
})();
```

I had to change the  `assetExts` in metro.config.js since I need to import glb file format. And I created a `declarations.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.jpeg';
declare module '*.gif';
declare module '*.bmp';
declare module '*.tiff';

declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from 'react';
  import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";
  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}
```

`index.ts` in images file

```
import ABC from "./svg/ABC.svg";
import SunAVG from "./svg/SunAVG.svg";

export {ABC, SunAVG};
```

Here is my path of those files:

```
metro.config.js
package.json
     |-> src
        |-> Types
          |-> declaration.d.ts
        |-> asset
          |-> images
            |-> avg
              |-> ABC.svg
            |-> index.ts
```

Will an SVG file be affected by the path?

Comment: Your directory is called `avg` not `svg`

Comment: @Reyno OMG!!!! it works!!! low mistake for me